# Add "Delete" button to my Theme

Tags: theme-development

I'd like to be able to delete my custom theme from within Wordpress. This option is available for the default themes, via the screenshot link below.

There is a red "Delete" link in the Theme management area, but it isn't available for my custom theme.

How can I enable this for a custom theme?

http://screencast.com/t/25h7k08vrE

Comment: Solution was so obvious... I was looking for an API to add the functionality to the theme, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete your theme when it is activated. You must deactivate the theme before the link will appear to delete it.